# pcap pakage to python project error is pcap.h not found

Tags: python, libpcap

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pcap (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pcap

Comment: You're giving very little information about the environment you're in, what tools you're using and what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: window/pycharm/anaconda(python2.7)

Answer (score 1):

The Python package name is `libpcap`, not `pcap`.

Comment: why say pcap.h not found,i should add any file